# How to set default printer in selection list asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, printing, vbscript

I have a problem. I have to set a custom printer in the print dialogue while working on client side environment. By using `windows.print()` I can see the list of printers but how can I choose the printer of my own choice from that list when the print dialogue is open.

Comment: JavaScript has no control over that.

Comment: Hi @epascarello can you please guide me how can i achieve this goal in silverlight or vb script.

Comment: I do not know. Did you search stackoverflow, you are not the only one that asked this.

Comment: ya looking for alternates but still unable to find anything on this